# Why wasn't Bruce Wayne shot too?

Tags: batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, dc

How come Joe Chill killed Bruce Wayne's parents and he didn't kill Bruce? And why did he kill Bruce's parents?

Comment: +1 for a nice question. I happens to have been asked before, but that's not a bad thing, so don't worry. :)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know I'm kinda new. But thanks for not being mad:) @RedCaio

Comment: Duplicate questions make it easier to find the answer since the different wordings make them that much more likely to show up in a search, if that makes sense. Obviously try to search around first, but if you don't find it and you ask a question, don't sweat it if it turns out to be a duplicate. :)

Comment: Glad your cool about it:). I'll watch what I ask next time. @RedCaio